# Why does my mixed model converge using lmer, but no lme?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, intervention-analysis

My aim is to measure the effect of an intervention (policy change) on a dependent variable that was recorded yearly (as was demonstrated at https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3415557/).

The same policy change took place in 4 different countries at 4 different points in time, therefore, time before and after the intervention varies from country to country. As there is only limited data for each country overall (20 to 30 data points), I pooled the data to conduct an analysis through generalized linear mix modeling. In total, the dataset includes 102 observations.

My main interest is the policy change effect for each country and an overall policy change effect.

My model includes the following:

- random intercepts
- random effects of time (random slopes)
- random effects of the policy change (modeled through the interaction of time and policy change)

At first, I used lme4 to build the model:

```
model <- lmer(rate ~ (1 + time * policy | country) + time * policy,
               data = data)
```

The model converged, but only with giving the following warning: `boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular`

However, as I am dealing with longitudinal data, I also want to account for autocorrelation, which is why I used nlme instead:

```
modelB <- lme(rate ~ time*policy, 
               random = ~ 1 + time * policy | country,
               correlation = corAR1(form = ~ time | country),
               data = data)
```

Unfortunately, the model won't converge now, telling me:

`nlminb problem, convergence error code = 1; message = iteration limit reached without convergence (10)`

Increasing the maximum iterations did not resolve this issue.

How come building the model works with one function, but not with the other? Is there something wrong with the formula?

Comment: How are time and policy stored? As factors? If so, that could be part of the problem. See this very informative post on using factors in the random parts of `lmer`. https://m-clark.github.io/posts/2020-03-01-random-categorical/

Comment: @ErikRuzek Thanks for your input. Time is an equally spaced continuous variable with < 0 before the policy change and > 0 after the change. Policy is an indicator variable with 0 in the pre-change period and 1 in the post-change period. Both are stored as numeric. For simpler versions of the model, both the nlme and the lmer function work without issues.

Comment: What if you remove policy from the random part of the model so it's just `(time|country)` in `lmer`?

Comment: @ErikRuzek This let's the model converge, however, it doesn't represent my research question accordingly. Right now I am looking into reducing the complexity of the model by removing the correlations among the random sloples!

Comment: Just a thought...sometimes you don't have the data to properly test your RQ. It's pretty rare in my field to see random slope for an interaction. The random slope for time combined with the fixed time by policy interaction is testing perhaps a slightly different research question, but is it close enough?